# Sql: SELECT rows with little time difference

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

`event_id    eventtypeid    eventtimestamp`

that describes time events that can be close to each other. I want to find the pairs of events, where eventtypes are equal and the difference between timestamps is no logner than 3 miliseconds.

Is it in generally possible in sql? How can I formulate such a request?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What do you want to do if there is a row with two "matches", one on each side? Is that two sets of pairs or one triplet?

Comment: @Tom H, tiplets are impossible :) or if they occure, i can be happy with all this events broken in pairs with each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  event_table   AS first
INNER JOIN
  event_table   AS second
    ON  second.eventtypeid     = first.eventtypeid
    AND second.eventtimestamp >  first.eventtimestamp
    AND second.eventtimestamp <= first.eventtimestamp + INTERVAL '3 milliseconds'
```

Answer (score 5):

Queries like these are generally best solved with a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT eventtypeid, first, second, diff
FROM (
  SELECT eventtypeid, event_id AS first, lead(event_id) OVER w AS second,
         lead(eventtimestamp) OVER w - eventtimestamp AS diff
  FROM event_table
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY eventtypeid ORDER BY eventtimestamp)
) sub
WHERE diff <= interval '3 milliseconds';
```

This is usually much faster than a self-join.